# How can I enable Hotlink Protection on a Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, hotlinking

what is the full code to stop sites from displaying images from my site. Only search engines should be allowed.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can manage the hotlink protection from cpanel as well.

[image: See here]

Also you can link that to .htaccess file as well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://yoursitename.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g?|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

[Reference URL](https://www.webnots.com/enable-image-hotlink-protection-for-wordpress-site/)

Comment: thank you for answering but is google allowed in the above code?